# Can the Windows Phone 7 Series emulator be made to run on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, emulation, windows-phone-7

Well thats all there is to it...is this possible?  I understand that officially it's not supported but has anyone figured it out?  I have some work to do where XP would be the preferred platform.  I would expect that users of the actual device are not required to use Windows 7 so it stands to reason that this can be done.  Any poitners in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
brian

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I work for a large mobile silicon vendor with many, many developers working on WP7. Our corporate standard is Windows XP, and I can promise you that a bunch of very bright people have spent a lot of time trying to get this to work.

Bottom line is that we've never succeeded reliably enough to make it usable as a working environment, so our IT department has rolled out Virtualized Windows 7 images to run on XP desktops.

If it's an option for you, Vista is alleged to work - I've never checked as we did not roll out Vista corporately.

Sorry not to have a more helpful answer.

P.S. Wanted to add that the final devices most likely will not support XP. At least today, the connectivity apps and the like require Vista or Windows 7, and I very much doubt that this will change.

Comment: Thanks this confirms my strong suspicions - i'm glad that i did not kill too much time trying to get this to work.  I just hate to write something off as impossible before consulting the community.